# .htaccess Not Found Page For Specific Folder

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404, customization

I'm trying to display a page for not found pages in a subfolder. It must affect just the subfolder. For example, it will display default notfound page file in mydomain.com/doesntexists.html, but it will display my custom notfound page in mydomain.com/files . How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can have this rule in `/subfolder/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolder/

RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```